# Parse/tokenize objective-c with objective-c (iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, parsing, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, tokenize

What are the options available of parsing and/or tokenizing Objective-C on iPhone?

Essentially I'm thinking of parsing/tokenizing enough to power syntax highlighting and autocompletion at somewhat the same level as Xcode does.

Comment: ... maybe I missed something critical.  You want to run this on the iPhone itself, or just on iPhone targeted applications?

Comment: @IraBaxter oh, sorry for the unclarity! Yes I want to run this on  iPhone itself, not only obj-c code targeted for iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old, but this might help someone else.

Apple already provides the (very nice) [CFStringTokenizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/index.html), with support for multiple languages. [Here's](http://sssslide.com/speakerdeck.com/mattt/natural-language-processing-in-objective-c) a good presentation on that, including sample code. In case tokenization is enough, that should do it.

If parsing is required however (it shouldn't for syntax highlight) there's [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/index.html) or C-based solutions, such as [YACC](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/).

Best.